# systemd job wait for DNS lookup

Tags: networking, dns, systemd

I've got a startup task via systemd that fails as it is unable to resolve an IP address it should be accessing via DNS. I consistently get and error indicating a `Temporary Error in Name Resolution`. I've tried various combinations of assigning `network-online.target`, `nss-lookup.target`, and `systemd-resolved.service` to the tasks `Wants`, `Required`, and `After` tags but no dice. I still cannot get the job to start consistently without producing failure on DNS lookup. Any suggestions? Posted an example of what I'm trying to do below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Does some stuff
Before=multi-user.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target systemd-resolved.service
Requires=network-online.target nss-lookup.target systemd-resolved.service
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target systemd-resolved.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=myuser
SyslogIdentifier=calibration_update
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'myservice_command'
RestartSec=5s
Restart=False
LimitNOFILE=1024000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/867830/systemd-start-service-only-after-dns-is-available ?